# Put block of bash code in a subshell

Tags: bash, shell-script

I was hoping that this might work:

```
echo "starting";
{
 cd "$HOME/foobar"
 echo "rolo" > file.txt
}
echo "ending";
```

where the subshell code would happen between the curly braces, but that syntax appears incorrect, how can I do this?

Comment: Use parens instead of braces

Comment: there's nothing wrong with braces in your example
it works , no syntax error. What are you getting as err. message?

Comment: Better question to ask is why do you need subshell here in the first place ? Can you explain the context of what you're trying to actually achieve ?

Comment: I just wanted to run some commands that would not affect the other commands, that's all

Comment: So in this example, you want the directory to not be changed for the lines following the block. That part is a bit unclear. (I know it's a couple years later and it's been answered, but I just found this so maybe someone else will appreciate the clarification.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [bash doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) you can use either parenthesis or braces for grouping, but if you use parenthesis you'll get a subshell instead.  So to run your commands in a subshell use:

```
echo "starting"
(
    cd "$HOME/foobar"
    echo "rolo" > file.txt
)
echo "ending"
```

though for this example, you could just

```
echo "rolo" > "$HOME/foobar/file.txt"
```

Comment: right, yeah the example was contrived...in some cases we must cd in order to install things easier, so yeah

Comment: @AlexanderMills indeed, also, consider `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd` for those cases as another possible solution

Comment: yeah thanks, what's the main advantage of `pushd`/`popd`?

Comment: They'll do the cd and "uncd" without needing to explicitly track where to go back and without needing to create a subshell

Comment: Ahh ok thx i will try it